# where is the ghc 7.4.1 branch?

Tags: haskell, ghc, building

Sorry this is a dumb question; how do I download the GHC 7.4.1 branch? I want to play around with the ConstraintKinds. The default branch seems to say it's version 7.3. I did look around a little bit, but didn't see anything helpful, or any branch named "7.4" on the github repository. Thanks!

(P.S. It might be helpful to add the info to http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/milestone/7.4.1 if you are a GHC developer?)

Comment: My first reaction mirrored kbyrd's answer - what makes you think 7.4 has it's own branch yet?  There's been no mention of a release date or candidate.  (NB I didn't downvote you)

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Max Bolingbroke makes a mention of it in his blog entry on ConstraintKinds, "Try it out for yourself in GHC 7.4 and find out!" ( http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/?p=127 ).

Comment: @gatoatigrado When he posted that, he probably expected 7.4 to come out sooner, there was no plan for a 7.2.2 release in September.

Comment: I also don't understand why this question was downvoted.

Answer (score 5):

There's no 7.4 branch yet. Lots of things that shall go into 7.4 are already in HEAD, though, so if you can't wait for constraint kinds, try it out in 7.3 (aka HEAD for now), until some time before the release, the 7.4 branch is created.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the [GHC Oct-2011 Status Report](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Status/Oct11) mentioned that

> GHC is still humming along, with the 7.2.1 release (more of a "technology preview" than a stable release) having been made in August, and attention now focused on the upcoming 7.4 branch. By the time you read this, the 7.4 branch will have been created, and will be in "feature freeze". We will then be trying to fix as many bugs as possible before releasing later in the year.

However, in a [libraries@haskell.org post](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2011-November/017047.html) from early November, SPJ informed us regarding the aforementioned GHC 7.4 branch/freeze that

> Yes, we're supposed to be but we have two big additions nearly ready but not quite validate free so we have pushed it out a few days.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download#snapshots, I don't see any mention of a 7.4.1 branch. HEAD seems to have only 7.3. Are you sure one has been created yet?

Comment: Well, it seems to have a milestone page, so I was guessing it would have corresponding code where people are fixing bugs for the milestone.

Comment: With trac or other wiki/bug/development trackers it's common to create a couple of far-out milestones before work actually begins.

Comment: Yup. There are already tickets milestoned for 7.6.1.